# Get token from OKTA API - Java (plain) example

Tags: java, httprequest, okta

I've created an account on OKTA environment [here](https://developer.okta.com/).
I searched on the net, but I couldn't find any examples on how to get access token from OKTA API. I'm looking for some example in "plain" Java code. But if there is something in any SDK, I'll be happy. 
I tried to create an HTTP request (POST), to **/token** endpoint. I've used **cliend_id** and **client_secret** - in body. I've also tried to put in into header as basic authentication (before that, I encoded **client_id:client_secret** with Base64), but I still getting unauthorized (401).

Comment: Hrrmm a login endpoint should not require a token to be present.... that would not make very much sense?

Comment: I don't understand. Which endpoint? Could you describe a litlle more?

Comment: You are saying you want to hit the `OKTA API` to retrieve an access token (this would be considered a login endpoint).... but you are getting a 401? How can an endpoint that is used to retrieve tokens require a token to be present?

Comment: You're right, but that endpoint needs client_id and client_secret, and few settings to work. Maybe my HTTP request is configured in wrong way, and that's why I'm getting an error. Because of that, I'm looking for working example of that.

Comment: For future reference, the [okta-oauth-java](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java) is the SDK for manually retrieving auth tokens. I know it handles username + pass authn, I don't know if it can handle your client_id + client_secret = token use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I have a solution. The problem was wrong configuration on OKTA. 
For those who needs working example, I'll share my tested code (believe me, it works)

```
 public String GetToken() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .build();

    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://YOUR_OKTA_DOMAIN/oauth2/default/v1/token"))
            .headers("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET".getBytes()),
                    "Accept", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(
                    "&grant_type=client_credentials" ))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<?> response = client.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());       

    return response.body().toString();
}
```

On Okta you need to have created additional scope for Authorization Server. This scope should be default, or if you don't want to set default scope, you have to add it in body as

```
.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(
                    "&grant_type=client_credentials" + 
                    "scope=SCOPE_NAME"))
```

Comment: I need a working example for my desktop application??!! could you help @Marcin

Comment: Sorry, I can't share this app, because it's commercial. But please ask, I'll try to help you with that.